# Elasticsearch modify asciifolding

Tags: elasticsearch, unicode, full-text-search, ascii

ASCII Folding Token Filter folds "Ə"/"ə"(U+018F / U+0259) characters to "A"/"a". I need to modify or add fold to "E"/"e". `char_filter` doesn't help and doesn't preserve original

Add analyzer:

```
curl -XPUT 'localshot:9200/myix/_settings?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "default" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "standard",
                    "filter" : ["standard", "my_ascii_folding"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "my_ascii_folding" : {
                    "type" : "asciifolding",
                    "preserve_original" : true
                }
            }
        }
}
'
```

Test result:

```
http://localhost:9200/myix/_analyze?text=üöğıəçşi_ÜÖĞIƏÇŞİ&filter=my_ascii_folding

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "uogiacsi_UOGIACSI",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 17,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "üöğıəçşi_ÜÖĞIƏÇŞİ",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 17,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: take a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html

Comment: I've already tried it and noted in my question, it doesn't preserve original

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at Lucene's [`ASCIIFoldingFilter.java`](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/e2521b2a8baabdaf43b92192588f51e042d21e97/lucene/analysis/common/src/test/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/TestASCIIFoldingFilter.java#L211) source file, it doesn indeed seem like `Ə` gets folded into an `E` and not a `A`. Even the [ICU folding filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.2/analysis-icu-folding.html) which is `asciifolding` on steroids, does the same folding.

However, there's an [interesting discussion](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T132637) on the subject and it seems that given the pronunciation it should be folded into an `a` and not a `e`:

> A quick search on English or French Wikipedia, where it currently gets folded, shows that it gets folded to an a! I would have expected an e based on orthography, but a makes sense in terms of pronunciation (in English, at least).

Someone else even thinks that neither `a` nor `e` makes sense:

> That seems like a really bad decision. I don't think ə should fold to either of a or e.

Anyway, I don't think there is a way except using a char_filter or [extending the `ASCIIFoldingFilter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.2/plugin-authors.html) and bundling it into an ES analysis plugin yourself.